# How to get the Handle Id from Process, HWND programmatically?

Tags: c, hwnd

I try to get Handle ID of opened applications (windows).

I run `Window detective` program, (like spy++) to verify that I get proper values.

For testing I try to get only one Handle Id pointed by red arrow (see the image):

[image]

So I have program that gives me process id and thread Id but not 1st Child Handle ID.

In my case I took `calc.exe`, but actually I need to do that for all `exe` applications:

**readWindow.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <psapi.h> 

HMODULE getModulePid(DWORD processID, char* searchStr){ // gets the module by the module name from an explicit process

   HANDLE hProcess;
   HMODULE hMods[1024];
   TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
   DWORD cbNeeded;

   if(hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID ))
   {
    if(EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
    unsigned int k;
    for(k = 0; k < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); ++k )
    {
        if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[k], szModName,  sizeof(szModName)/sizeof(TCHAR)))
        {

        //printf( "fess pid: %u modname: %s\n", processID, szModName );

        if(strstr(szModName, searchStr))
        {
            printf( "pid: &#37;u modname: %s\n", processID, szModName );
            CloseHandle( hProcess );
            return hMods[k];
        }
       }
    }//for
  }     
}  
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    return NULL;
}

HMODULE getModule(char* searchStr){ // gets the module by the modul name from all processes
   DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) ) return NULL;
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    HMODULE hmodule;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; ++i )
    {
        if(hmodule = getModulePid(aProcesses[i], searchStr))
         {
         return hmodule;
          }
         }
    return NULL;
}


HMODULE getModuleHwnd(HWND hwnd){ // gets the module from a window
   DWORD pid;
   DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid ); // !!??!!
   printf( "hwnd tid: %u\n", tid  );
    printf( "hwnd pid: %u\n", pid  );
   return getModulePid(pid, ".exe");
}

HMODULE hModuleT;
char* searchStrT;

BOOL CALLBACK shownWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam){ // EnumWindows callback
   if(hModuleT) return TRUE;

    char pcWinTitle[256];

    if(GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)) return TRUE; // whats that?
    GetWindowText(hwnd, pcWinTitle, 1024);
    if(strstr(pcWinTitle, searchStrT)){  
        printf( "wndtitle: %s\n", pcWinTitle);                                      
        hModuleT = getModuleHwnd(hwnd);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

HMODULE getModuleByWndTitle(char* searchStr){ // gets the module from a window title
    searchStrT = searchStr;
    EnumWindows(shownWindow, 0);
    return hModuleT;
}


int main()
{

    //EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);

    printf("find by name ... \n");
     getModule("calc.exe");
     printf("\nfind by title ... \n");
   getModuleByWndTitle("Calculator");

    printf("Done");


    return 0;
}
```

Run from `minGW`:

> $ gcc -L/local/lib -I/local/include -o readWindow readWindow.c -lpsapi

Output:

```
find by title ...
wndtitle: Calculator
hwnd tid: 33364
hwnd pid: 25440
Done
```

**How can I get the Handle from Process?**

I'm sure it should be some 1-2 rows of code.

```
DWORD dwValue .....

printf("The value in hexa: 0X%.8X(%d).\n", dwValue);
```

it should be `0x007B137C`

From Spy++ I need this value, red arrow:

[image]

Comment: A handle is not a unique value/identifier. If two applications have a handle to something, they won't have the same hexadecimal value, so comparing the output to your program and the output to a 3rd party app doesn't make sense.

Comment: But `CalcFrame` has `text` - `Calculator`, moreever, when I use `Window Detective` search, I get only one window, see my Edit

Comment: "handle ID" is not a Windows term. What do you mean by it?

Comment: In `Window detective` they call it `Handle`, Spy++ calls it `Window Handle`. both represent 8 digits in hexa. I need this value to share current window over SIP video in my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty easy but for me tricky a bit.

I just need to print pointer `HWND hwnd` with `%p`.

So I added to my code:

```
char szBuff[512];
sprintf(szBuff, "%p", hwnd);

printf( "Found .... hWnd: %s\n", szBuff);
```

And got what I need:

```
Found .... hWnd: 007B137C
```

**[EDIT]**

Working code example:

**readWindow.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <psapi.h> 

HMODULE getModulePid(DWORD processID, char* searchStr){ // gets the module by the module name from an explicit process

   HANDLE hProcess;
   HMODULE hMods[1024];
   TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
   DWORD cbNeeded;

   if(hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID ))
   {
    if(EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
    unsigned int k;
    for(k = 0; k < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); ++k )
    {
        if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[k], szModName,  sizeof(szModName)/sizeof(TCHAR)))
        {

        //printf( "fess pid: %u modname: %s\n", processID, szModName );

        if(strstr(szModName, searchStr))
        {
            printf( "pid: &#37;u modname: %s\n", processID, szModName );
            CloseHandle( hProcess );
            return hMods[k];
        }
       }
    }//for
  }     
}  
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    return NULL;
}

HMODULE getModule(char* searchStr){ // gets the module by the modul name from all processes
   DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) ) return NULL;
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    HMODULE hmodule;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; ++i )
    {
        if(hmodule = getModulePid(aProcesses[i], searchStr))
         {
         return hmodule;
          }
         }
    return NULL;
}


HMODULE getModuleHwnd(HWND hwnd){ // gets the module from a window
   DWORD pid;
   DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid ); // !!??!!
   printf( "hwnd tid: %u\n", tid  );
    printf( "hwnd pid: %u\n", pid  );
   return getModulePid(pid, ".exe");
}

HMODULE hModuleT;
char* searchStrT;

BOOL CALLBACK shownWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam){ // EnumWindows callback
   if(hModuleT) return TRUE;

    char pcWinTitle[256];

    if(GetWindow(hwnd, GW_OWNER)) return TRUE; // whats that?
    GetWindowText(hwnd, pcWinTitle, 1024);

    if(strstr(pcWinTitle, searchStrT))
    {  
        printf( "wndtitle: %s\n", pcWinTitle);                                      
        hModuleT = getModuleHwnd(hwnd);

        char szBuff[512];
       sprintf(szBuff, "%p", hwnd);

       printf( "Found .... hWnd: %s\n", szBuff); 

    }

    return TRUE;
}

HMODULE getModuleByWndTitle(char* searchStr){ // gets the module from a window title
    searchStrT = searchStr;
    EnumWindows(shownWindow, 0);
    return hModuleT;
}


int main()
{

    //EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);

    printf("find by name ... \n");
     getModule("calc.exe");
     printf("\nfind by title ... \n");
   getModuleByWndTitle("Calculator");

    printf("Done");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to agree, how to use printf() correctly doesn't appear to be much of an answer to "How can I get the Handle from Process?"  If you are happy with this answer, why on Earth did you put a bounty on the question?  What problem are you still trying to solve?

Comment: I have screen share application that can stream specific window or full screen. screen share application uses only API through registry where I need to put Handle ID (as hexa) of specific window. I can fetch Process Id or Thread from  hwnd but took me full day to find how to get Handle Id. Till now no one did tell me so I found that I can fetch handler ID from pointer. Im not "C" programmer so if you know proper way to do that, 50 points + V is yours. Thanks

Comment: @rogerdpack, done, thanks, IDK, if its right way, and I can't give to myself 50 points

Comment: @HansPassant `why on Earth did you put a bounty on the question?` because I had to find answer during 1 week and found by myself through 4 days since no one didn't answer.